# How do I get Crucible and Vanguard marks?

Tags: destiny

Several vendors require Crucible and Vanguard marks for purchasing certain items, but the tooltips say nothing about how to get them. How and when do I get these marks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Crucible Marks are obtained by anything and everything PvP. The amount you get varies on performance and game mode.

Vanguard Marks you get by doing the Strike playlist (opens at around level 17). You can also gain marks at a much slower rate by doing other PvE interactions, like patrolling and random events that appear during patrols. The amount you get varies on the Strike Difficulty selection you chose.

Both kinds of Marks have a weekly earn limit of 100 before you can gain more again. The time renews on Tuesdays, IIRC.

Comment: I think the daily and weekly heroic quest also give Vanguard marks, not positive on that though. They open at level 20.

Comment: One other things to note is that while you can convert Vanguard rank into faction rank by wearing that faction's item, you still need crucible marks, not vanguard marks, to buy from the factions.

Comment: So with the armband (warlock) you will gain faction reputation (rank), but not faction marks, do I understand it correctly? I will need to play PvP matches to gain the marks required, even if the rank gets high enough from strike missions wearing the requisite class item?

Comment: yes @LasseV.Karlsen, Faction Items all require Crucible Marks to purchase.

Comment: I think there's a level req as well.  I feel like I only started getting marks once I hit 18.

Comment: I agree, I'm level 13 and I don't have any crucible or vanguard marks yet. I have been getting crucible/vanguard reputation, but I can't see anywhere this is stored?

Comment: @mmatthews you can still get them from doing public events at any level, but they are still relatively rare.

Comment: @ahillier88 The best way I've found to see your rep is to go to the vendor that uses that rep. The circle on the left will include your level and progress towards the next level.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can trade in materials like Spinmetal with the Crucible robot guy, 50 items at a time for Crucible marks + rep.
Helpful for those that know the farming routes & dont like the Crucible.